# AWS Glue - How to exclude rows where string does not match a date format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a dataset with a datecreated column. this column is typically in the format 'dd/MM/yy' but sometimes it has garbage text. I want to ultimately convert the column to a DATE and have the garbage text as a NULL value.

I have been trying to use resolveChoice, but it is resulting in all null values.

> data_res = date_dyf.resolveChoice(specs =
>   [('datescanned','cast:timestamp')])

Sample data

```
3,1/1/18,text7  
93,this is a test,text8  
9,this is a test,text9  
82,12/12/17,text10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting a DynamicFrame into Spark's DataFrame and parse date using [to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/#to_date) function:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date

df = date_dyf.toDF
parsedDateDf = df.withColumn("datescanned", to_date(df["datescanned"], "dd/MM/yy"))
dyf = DynamicFrame.fromDF(parsedDateDf, glueContext, "convertedDyf")
```

If a string doesn't match the format a `null` value will be set